# Sequelize - query other table inside where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do something and do not know if this is possible with sequelize. Basically I have this code snippet running on graphQl and basically what this does is to find kits on the kits table and then verify if the same id exists on the "users" table. If not, it returns them, if yes it does not. However now we need to scale this to have pagination and the current snippet is not so scalable. That is why I had the idea to just include the for loop in the where clause or somehow to check there, but really do not know any command on mySql that allows to do this.

Do you have any tip?

```
async findKitsWithResultNoReg2(_, {search}) {
      try {
        let promises = []
        const a1 = await db.kits.findAll({
          where: {
            [Op.and]: [
              { result: { [Op.or]: [1, 2, 3] } }, 
              { cp: 0 },
              {[Op.or]: [
                { kitID: { [Op.like]: '%' + search + '%' } }]}
            ]
          }
        })
        for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
          const a2 = await db.users.findByPk(a1[i].dataValues.kitID)
          if (a2 === null) {
            const a3 = {
              kitID: a1[i].dataValues.kitID,
              result: a1[i].dataValues.result,
              date: a1[i].dataValues.resultDate
            }
            promises.push(a3)
          }
        }
        
        return Promise.all(promises)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 async findKitsWithResultNoReg() {
      try {
        const a0 = await sequelize.query(`SELECT kitID, result, resultDate from kits where result in (1,2,3) and cp = 0 and archived = 0 and not Exists(select kitID from users where kits.kitID = users.kitID) order by resultDate desc`,  { type: QueryTypes.SELECT })
        const a1 = JSON.stringify(a0)
        return a1
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
```